# Perl/Tk System Function Error?

Tags: perl

I am making an "all-in-one calculator" (I guess). Here is my code (I know I do not have all subroutines defined, I'm still working on this as you can see):

```
use 5.12.4;
use warnings;
use Tk;

##### Create MainWindow #####
my $button_menu = new MainWindow;
#############################

##### MainWindow Buttons#####
my $calculator_button = $button_menu->Button(-text=>"Calculator",
                                         -width=>10,
                                         -relief=> 'raised',
                                         -command=>\&open_calculator)->pack();

my $formulas_button = $button_menu->Button(-text=>"Formulas",
                                   -width=>10,
                                   -relief=> 'raised',
                                   -command=>\&open_formulas)->pack();


sub open_calculator{
    system(qq{start "C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe"});
}

MainLoop;
```

Why does the system function not open the Windows calculator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
system(qq{start calc});
```

Comment: Without `start` the system call waits until `calc` exits before the script proceeds, which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
system('start C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe');
```